# PhpStorm не видит Pug

Tags: phpstorm, pug

Добрый вечер, друзья.
Нужна ваша помощь! Проблема заключается в том, что PhpStorm не видит Pug.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я установил плагин Pug(ex Jade), перезапускал Шторм, не помогает. В чем может быть проблема, может кто-то знает? Заранее, спасибо!

Comment: а что значит "не видит"? Не ту иконку использует? Это только с файлом `test.pug`, или с любыми `*.pug` файлами?

Comment: я бы посоветовала проверить настройки ассоциаций в Settings | Editor | File Types - какие patterns настроены для типа Jade?

Answer (score 1):

Установите через Settings -> Plugins поддержку `pug` и `Jade`. Если не сработает, тогда ассоциируйте файлы `pug` c `Jade`.